# Storing/tabling interaction frequency between variables

Tags: r

I want to keep track of the interactions between R.P, R.S, R.R, P.R, P.S, etc:

```
history <- c("R", "P", "P", "S", "S", "S")
ix <- 1:length(history)
for (i in ix) {
    y <- history[c(ix[i], ix[i+1])];
    z <- interaction(y[[1]],y[[2]])
    print(z)
}
```

Right now my code produces:

```
[1] R.P
Levels: R.P
[1] P.P
Levels: P.P
[1] P.S
Levels: P.S
[1] S.S
Levels: S.S
[1] S.S
Levels: S.S
[1] <NA>
Levels:
```

When I actually want something like this:

```
R.P 1
P.P 1
P.S 1
S.S 2
```

How can I adjust/refactor my code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the `interaction` between the current and the preceding element by removing the first observation and last observation of the 'history', use the `drop=TRUE` argument in `interaction` to remove the unused levels, call `factor` again with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of the vector (if we are particular about the order in the output), get the frequency with `table` and convert to 'data.frame' (`as.data.frame`)

```
 v1 <- interaction(history[-length(history)], history[-1], drop=TRUE) 
 as.data.frame(table(factor(v1, levels=unique(v1))))
 #  Var1 Freq
 #1  R.P    1
 #2  P.P    1
 #3  P.S    1
 #4  S.S    2
```

Or as @A.Webb mentioned in the comments, a slightly different version would be using `lag` from the `base R`

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(interaction(stats::lag(history),history))), Freq>0)
#  Var1 Freq
#1  P.P    1
#2  R.P    1
#7  P.S    1
#9  S.S    2
```

Comment: Or perhaps `as.data.frame(table(interaction(stats::lag(history),history)))`

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks for the comments.  I added in the post